# What is the best way of doing assertions in Robot Framework?

Tags: java, junit, robotframework, assertion

I'm using Robot Framework with Java. My question is:
what is the best way of doing assertions in Robot Framework?
Should I import JUnit (or a similar library) and use if for assertions in my own keyword?

Is there a keyword library for assertions? I mean a library that contains keywords something like this:

```
Assert True &{value_to_check}
Assert List Contains &{list_of_elements} &{element_to_find} # using java equals method
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the majority of the use cases you don't need an external library (especially a java one), but check what is baked in the [BuiltIn](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html) and the [Collections](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html) libraries.
You have to explicitly import the latter, while BuiltIn is always available.

All keywords that have "should" in their name are asserts - [`Should Be True`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Be%20True), [`Should Contain`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Contain) (that's for membership - works on lists, dicts, strings - any container), [`List Should Contain Sub List`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#List%20Should%20Contain%20Sub%20List), and some even do type casting on the arguments - [`Should Be Equal As Numbers`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Be%20Equal%20As%20Integers).

This pattern (of "should" being asserts) is followed in other (external) libraries - in the [SeleniumLibrary](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html), for example.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!